# Format data from a function, or pull out globals

Tags: powershell, global-variables

I have been working on a script that will check PCs/ Servers for specific information based upon my organization.  I have created this code from what I have found, mangled, modified and composed from the web and this site.

It will read a CSV file and look for variables to compare.  Originally it would output to screen using **Write-Host** with colors, and it worked well.  The first of the ***IF*** was if the registry matched the expected value, it would turn green.  Otherwise the **Else** would turn the output line red.  However, Now I am wanting to send it to Powershell Excel Module by Doug Finke for archiving.

The **CSV** file has four fields description of what I am looking for, Which registry Hive to check, Key, Value, and What I want it to read.

When I export the data, it now comes out separated into different rows, and is hard to read when the variable is printed.

I now would prefer to get the variables out from the function as a Global, but I have not had luck with that either.  I have read numerous examples, and even some on here, but not managed to get the data where I can work with it or manipulate it.

```
Function Check-Reg-Values(){
    foreach ($RegLine in $RegCSV){

        $array =@() 
        $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($RegLine.Hive, $server) 
        $key = $reg.OpenSubkey($RegLine.RegKey)
           If ($key){
           $value = $key.GetValue($RegLine.RegValue)  
           $array += $value
           #Write-output $array -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Black
                If ($array -eq $RegLine.WhatShouldBe){
                Write-Output "Registry =" + $RegLine.RegKey +"="+ $array + $RegLine.WhatShouldBe
                }
                Else
                {
                Write-Output "Registry =" + $RegLine.RegKey +' ='+ $array + $RegLine.WhatShouldBe
                }
           }
           Else
           {
           Write-Output 'Registry Key ' $RegLine.RegKey 'does not exist' 
           }
    }
}
```

Please give some guidance on either manipulating the data so that it is usable, or getting the globals out, or even better both.

**Sample output Below.** You will notice the "+" signs, I have tried so many different things to get this to look correctly.

```
    Registry =
+
Control Panel\Accessibility\ToggleKeys
+ =+
62
+
58
Registry =
+
SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\SMC
+ =+
0
+
1
Registry =
+
SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main
+ =+
1
+
0
Registry =
+
SOFTWARE\Altiris\Altiris Agent
+=+
1
+
1
```

I appreciate any help on here, and I promise that I read a lot before asking questions here.

Comment: what keys are in that CSV file? What does your initial output really look like? otherwise, we're left to guess. Why are both output lines in that if statement the same? Otherwise, we are all left to guessing, which isn't conducive to helping you efficiently.

Comment: I added the output, and the information about the "duplicate" lines.  Originally they differentiated compliance by the color of the line.

Comment: @postanote ditto. If we can't see the original data, and the full scope of your code we're left to speculate. OP please provide more data on the original and we'll try to help